# Sitecore IFrame displays Page Editor ribbon

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, page-editor

I am working on integrating an `iframe` to a Sitecore template.
I have created the ASPX page and added that to the `iframe` in Sitecore template. (e.g. `/sitecore/content/Custom Editors/SampleIFrameEditor`)

It works fine, I can see my ASPX page gets rendered in the `iframe` control. Only issue is that it shows the "Page Editor" ribbon control on top (Home Advanced Expereience...), which I do not need to be displayed. (It's like I opened it up in Page Editor.)

How can I hide "Page Editor" options from this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

You could add `?sc_mode=normal` as a query string to your `iframe` `src` URL.