# Sitecore: Programmatically remove the Page Editor Tool bar on top

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, page-editor

I am  loading a page (item rendering e.g. /sitecore/content/.../Page) inside an IFrame. It shows the Page Editor ribbon as well. I want to hide that tool bar, it is not required in my scenario.

But if I set the source URL for IFrame like `http://mysite/somefolder/page.aspx` it does not display the Page Editor controls.

That means Page Editor controls gets loaded on demand. 
Need to know how to stop loading Page Editor controls on the page.
Please let me know if you know how to stop those controls being loaded to the page.

Comment: Hi Yan,  I dont need this page in Edit mode. I am using "/sitecore/content/Custom Editors/TestIFrameEditor" as the source link in the IFrame field. Therefore "?sc=normal" didn't work for me. I have tried your code sample on the Page load, for the 1st time it loads without the page editor. If you try to reload the item again it gives the "Resource not found" error. Please help....

Comment: I presume the comment was mean for me, not Yan? You double posted the question, the other question has some more relevant information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837537/sitecore-iframe-displays-page-editor-ribbon

I miss understood Sitecore IFrame vs HTML IFrame.

Did you try changing the `DisplayModeDuration` and see that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, I am hiding this ribbon with CSS, it's a very simple solution,

```
<style>
    /*Hide the edit mode ribbon panel appears in the iframes. Originally added this to Price strategy control.*/
    #scWebEditRibbon, #scCrossPiece
    {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because the page is in Edit mode. Will this page never need to loaded in the page editor? If not then you can add the following to the Page_Load event:

```
Sitecore.Context.Site.SetDisplayMode(Sitecore.Sites.DisplayMode.Normal, Sitecore.Sites.DisplayModeDuration.ResetAfterRequest);
```

Otherwise you can append `?sc_mode=normal` to the URL when setting the `src` of the iFrame to achieve the same thing. This way if you want to edit the page outside the iFrame you can use the standard Sitecore Page Editor features.

What were/are you setting the URL of the IFrame to currently (when you get the controls)?

Comment: setting the sc_mode to normal will also change the data source to web instead of master, which may not be the intent here. I think they want to view the preview content without the controls.